# How can i add files to the iso root folder?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to add a folder to the iso being built but anything I add to the iso folder location isn't included in the final iso.

My .bb do_install() installs the folder and files to ${iso}  directory. And ls shows they are there in /iso in build/tmp. And i get no errors

Is there any documentation on Bitbake to add files to the iso root folder?

All i can find is adding to the Rootfs.

Comment: Show the actual recipe, don't just vaguely describe it. As guenni  says a /iso directory doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by ios directory either.  Please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean by `ÌSO` an ISO-Image. So i recommend you take a look at this [part](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILES) of the yocto mega manual. Something like

```
FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/mydir1 ${bindir}/mydir2/myfile"
```

is needed to include installed files finally into the package `${PN}`. Of course you have to install then the package into your image build.

Comment: That adds to the image root filesystem and not the ISO file system. I am trying to add to the one with the dir: EFI, isolinux, loader, efi.img, initrd, rmc.db, rootfs.img, vmlinuz. the base of the ISO